# Where does macOS store information about Time Machine history?

Tags: time-machine

If you look in System Preferences » Time Machine, it will show you the Oldest/Latest/Next Backup times/dates, as shown here:

[image: Screenshot of Time Machine in System Preferences]

Does anyone know where that information is stored? Is there a .plist file somewhere that has it? Is it accessible in some other way other than opening the System Preference pane for Time Machine?

I tried googling for this but everything I found was just telling me to look in System Preferences for this information, and nothing about where it might be found in the system.

### Update

It appears that the file `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine.plist` contains a list of “SnapshotDates” which includes the first and most recent backup times/dates.

I could not seem to locate “Next Backup” time, however.

Comment: "Next Backup" might just be calculated based on the last time it run.

Comment: Yeah I'm wondering if that's the case. It seems to be scheduled for an hour after `ReferenceLocalSnapshotDate` in that same plist. I know it's possible (or used to be possible) to change how often Time Machine runs, but by default it's once per hour.

Comment: Nope. Further examination shows that `ReferenceLocalSnapshotDate` is not a reliable guide for when the next backup will be done.